Add list of hostnames to a constructed inventory
I am using AAP v2.4 and trying to create a smart inventory to add 10 individual hosts. I cannot use any filter because there is nothing in common with the servers to filter on. AAP smart inventory does not work very well because in order for me to create it, I have been using Advance > Name > iexact and then add each server name manually which is time consuming.
So I have been looking at constructed inventories to see if I can just paste in the names of the hosts separated with a comma but this is not working. This is what I have so far:
 plugin: constructed
 strict: true
 groups:
  winhosts: inventory_hostname == "server01","host04"

Is there a way to add the hostnames in one line? Something like this:
inventory_hostname == "server01,host04,another10,device5"

The constructed inventory will help you classify existing hots into groups. If I understand you correctly you want to create hosts rather. If that's indeed what you want, you are more likely to be looking for the generator inventory, rather. Or for a simple YAML one.
